# How do I get a constant's value when forming its name dynamically?

Tags: php, dynamic-variables

That title probably doesn't help much.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to get the value of a variable that has been set using `define(...)`, but using a 2nd variable to build the defined var's name.  Example will be clearer:

```
define('I_LOVE_YOU', 'xoxox');
$n = 'LOVE';

// how to get 'xoxox', using $n?  This won't work:
$defd = 'I_'.$n.'_YOU';
echo $defd;  // obviously echos 'I_LOVE_YOU', not 'xoxox'

// this will, but is awful
eval('echo I_'.$n.'_YOU;');  // echos 'xoxox'
```

Is there any other way to do this, w/o resorting to eval?

Comment: I edited the title to try and better reflect what you're asking, maybe it is more clear?

Comment: @nickb Sure that's a little better, though when trying to figure this out it was the verbiage of "defined" vs "constant" that caused me to run into a wall.  Future SOers might hit that same wall, so I'd lean towards keeping "defined" in the title.  Will defer to your take though, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval()`, use [`constant()`](http://php.net/constant):

```
define('I_LOVE_YOU', 'xoxox');
$n = 'LOVE';
echo constant('I_'.$n.'_YOU');
```

Comment: Nice, thanks. Found that myself a minute after asking, hate it when that happens!  Will accept answer as soon as SO will let me.